# is it valid smalldatetime?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

SQL Server 2005

How to check if given **date** is valid **smalldatetime**? Before converting datetime to smalldatetime, I already know that the value is valid datetime. But while converting datetime to smalldatetime, it is raising overflow error.

So I wanted to check if the value is valid smalldatetime and if it is then convert to smalldatetime else return NULL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @yourDateTime BETWEEN '19000101 00:00:00.000'
                                   AND '20790606 23:59:29.997'
            THEN CAST(@yourDateTime AS SMALLDATETIME)
            ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function here T[rouble With ISDATE And Converting To SMALLDATETIME](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Trouble_With_ISDATE_And_Converting_To_SMALLDATETIME) that you can use, name is `fnIsSmallDateTime`

There are also examples of how to use it

Answer (score 0):

When you get to SQL 2012 you may use `TRY_CONVERT`.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime,@yourDateTime)
```

Returns the date if it is a valid date, otherwise null.
**Will not work in a WHERE clause.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017